# Comparación de objetos en NodeJs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, array, object

Trabajo con **NodeJs**, específicamente estoy haciendo un robot que usa la **Discord API**. Uno de sus eventos, llamado `guildMemberUpdate` usa dos variables, `oldMember` y `newMember`. En el cual `newMember` extiende `GuildMember` y tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
GuildMember {
  guild: [Object],
  user: [Object],
  _roles: [Object],
  serverDeaf: false,
  serverMute: true,
  selfMute: undefined,
  selfDeaf: undefined,
  voiceSessionID: undefined,
  voiceChannelID: undefined,
  speaking: false,
  nickname: null,
  joinedTimestamp: 1481487406478,
  lastMessageID: '267258446351433731'
}
```

`GuildMember` tiene una serie de propiedades, un ejemplo de `GuildMember._roles`:

```
[
  '256969163493343232',
  '256985766792527872',
  '257006071888084993',
  '257035425548337163'
]
```

Ahora bien, lo que quiero hacer son dos cosas.

Primero, quiero obtener la diferencia de `GuildMember._roles` de ambas variables (`oldMember` y `newMember`), en la que por ejemplo:

```
// oldMember._roles
[
  '256969163493343232',
  '256985766792527872',
]

// newMember._roles
[
  '256969163493343232',
  '256985766792527872',
  '257006071888084993'
]
```

Me gustaría tener como salida `257006071888084993`.

El siguiente paso es que en la salida, valores en los que se diferencian deben ser insertados en `msg.guild.roles.get(ID)` (cada uno, si se añaden o se remueven más de un rango, quiero que cada ID sea insertada en la anterior línea de código).

Además, debe verificar si se añadido un rango, se ha removido, o ambos (si se añaden y se remueven rangos al mismo tiempo). Y devolver un mapa ordenado y unido por `', '`, es decir, `diff.map(r => r.name).slice(1).sort().join(', ')`.

En la última línea de código que he añadido, `.name` es un valor de `Role` (un objeto), y `diff` sería la variable resultante de la diferencia de los rangos. Y deben ser dos, uno que muestre los rangos añadidos (en el caso de que existan nuevos rangos) y otro que muestre los rangos removidos.

Comment: fijate que edite la respuesta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Primero, quiero obtener la diferencia de GuildMember._roles de ambas variables (oldMember y newMember), en la que por ejemplo:

Puedes hacerlo combinando `filter` e `indexOf`, filtrando aquellos elementos que no se encuentran en `oldMember`

Ejemplo:

```js
// oldMember._roles
var oldMember = [
  '256969163493343232',
  '256985766792527872',
  '999888288299232321',
]

// newMember._roles
var newMember = [
  '256969163493343232',
  '256985766792527872',
  '257006071888084993'
]


var nuevos = newMember.filter(function(i) { return oldMember.indexOf(i) < 0; });
var eliminados = oldMember.filter(function(i) { return newMember.indexOf(i) < 0; });

console.log(nuevos);
console.log(eliminados);
```

Para obtener los elementos eliminados, es igual, pero se invierten de orden los arreglos.

> El siguiente paso es que en la salida, valores en los que se diferencian deben ser insertados en msg.guild.roles.get(ID) (cada uno, si se añaden o se remueven más de un rango, quiero que cada ID sea insertada en la anterior línea de código).
>
> De los comentarios: msg.guild.roles.get(ID) debe ser ejecutado en cada rango añadido o removido (ya que me devuelve un objeto que contiene todas las propiedades que necesito para trabajar).

<strike>No conozco la API, pero de acuerdo a la [documentación](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/guild) `roles` es un array, por lo que puedes usar `push` y [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) (`...`) para insertar los elementos.</strike>

```
// resultado es el resultado el snippet anterior
msg.guild.roles.push(... resultado)
```

Entiendo que quieres *obtener* los datos cuyos IDs están en los arreglos antes obtenidos: nuevamente puedes usar `filter` para obtenerlos en base a los arreglos `nuevos` y `eliminados` antes calculados:

```
// este arreglo contendrá los roles agregados
var rolesNuevos = msg.guild.roles.filter(function(role) {
    // aca buscamos por id
    return nuevos.indexOf(role.id) !== -1; 
});

// este arreglo contendrá los roles eliminados
var rolesEliminados = msg.guild.roles.filter(function(role) { 
    // aca buscamos por id
    return eliminados.indexOf(role.id) !== -1; 
});
```

> Además, debe verificar si se añadido un rango, se ha removido, o ambos (si se añaden y se remueven rangos al mismo tiempo). Y devolver un mapa ordenado y unido por ', ', es decir, diff.map(r => r.name).slice(1).sort().join(', ').

La rutina que tienes estaria bien para: obtener un array de **los nombres** de los roles, pero salteando el primero (por el `slice(1)`). El problema con esto es que ambos ejemplos anteriores retronarían arreglos vacíos pues el `slice(1)` esta eliminando el único elemento en el resultado.

```
rolesNuevos.map(r => r.name).slice(1).sort().join(', ')
```

Quiza quieras...

```
var nombresNuevos = rolesNuevos.map(r => r.name).sort().join(',')
var nombresEliminados = rolesNuevos.map(r => r.name).sort().join(',')
```

Coméntame si entendí algo mal y lo revisamos.

Salu2

Comment: `msg.guild.roles.get(ID)` debe ser ejecutado en cada rango añadido o removido (ya que me devuelve un objeto que contiene todas las propiedades que necesito para trabajar).

Sobre el último quote, el programa debe procesar dos mapas, uno para los rangos añadidos y otro para los rangos removidos y deben estar ordenados alfabéticamente, para eso el `.map(r => r.name).slice(1).sort().join(', ')`, es el código con el que los ordenaría y los uniría con ', '

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/psfgoovu/ funcionando a la absoluta perfección, muchas gracias (obviamente el jsfiddle no va a funcionar ahí, pero en mi bot está funcionando).